L'adjectif « retombant » est-il synonyme de l'adjectif « tombant » ?
Le TLFi donne deux définitions à l'adjectif « retombant » :

« Qui pend librement, mollement. »
« Qui descend, qui s'incline en pente. »

Pour la 1re définition, il donne l'exemple de branches retombantes.
Il donne aussi une définition de l'adjectif « tombant » qui est : « Qui pend naturellement ou qu'on laisse pendre. » Cette définition me semble assez près de la 1re donnée plus haut pour « retombant ». Il y a aussi un exemple d'utilisation du mot « tombant » où on parle de sapins aux branches tombantes.
Je ne saisis pas bien la différence de sens entre les deux adjectifs, donc ma question porte sur cette différence. Les deux adjectifs sont-ils synonymes lorsqu'il s'agit de décrire quelque chose qui pend ? Est-ce que l'adjectif « retombant » ne peut pas être remplacé par l'adjectif « tombant » seulement lorsqu'on décrit quelque chose « qui descend, qui s'incline en pente » (synonymo.fr donne « descendre » comme synonyme de « tomber » donc je me demande si on pourrait employer « tombant » même dans ce sens) ?

RETOMBANT : parmi les définitions du Robert  Toucher terre après s'être élevé. Retomber après un saut : Le chat est retombé sur ses pattes. | S'abaisser (après avoir été levé) : Laisser retomber les bras. |  Cesser de se soutenir : L'intérêt ne doit pas retomber. Les SYNONYME du verbe retomber donne le contexte d'emploi : redescendre, baisser, chuter, rebaisser… la notion de tomber après s''être élevé est fondamentale.

La différence est celle-là même qui a conduit à distinguer les deux verbes tomber et retomber.

Dans certains contextes les deux adjectifs peuvent effectivement sembler pouvoir être employés de façon interchangeable dans la mesure où ils peuvent décrire le même mouvement mais personnellement je ne les emploierais pas forcément toujours l'un à la place de l'autre.
Quand il s'agit de plantes le terme le plus fréquent dans les jardineries spécialisées (que j'oppose aux grandes surfaces) est « plantes retombantes ». Même si on ne voit que les branches de la plante, lesquelles visuellement ont un mouvement entièrement orientées vers le bas, il y a la racine qui, elle, pousse du bas vers le haut, donc du point de vue de la croissance la plante a poussé vers le haut avant de croitre vers le bas. Cela n'exclut pas l'usage de « plantes  tombantes » par les non spécialistes ou même, rarement, par quelques spécialistes ; vu, par exemple, sur le site d'une jardinerie spécialisée :

Les plantes tombantes d'intérieur viennent dans une surprenante variété de formes, de tailles et d'exigences de soin.

dans ce cas l'emploi de « tombantes » ne décrit que ce qui est visuel et non pas une qualité appartenant à la plante toute entière. Même spécialiste des plantes, celui qui a écrit cette phrase, ne s'exprime que d'un point de vue de décorateur et pas de jardinier.
Le même usage s'applique aux branches. Une branche commence à pousser vers le haut à partir du tronc, et selon les espèces elle peut continuer à pousser vers le haut ou ensuite s'étendre vers le bas de façon naturelle, on parle dans ce cas d'espèces à « branches retombantes ». Une recherche sur internet avec "branches retombantes" me renvoie plus volontiers sur des sites spécialisés tels que jardineries et pépinières, il en va tout autrement de "branches tombantes" qui se rencontre le plus souvent sur des descriptions d'images ou de forums.
Je dirais que l'emploi de retombant qualifie une spécificité inhérente à la plante ou à l'objet. Par contre si j'emploie tombant je donne un point de vue, je décris ce que je vois ou  ressens. Dans l'exemple suivant du TLF (II B 4)  :

Parmi ce peuple de sapins aux branches tombantes, des présences se devinaient (ᴘᴏᴜʀʀᴀᴛ, Gaspard, 1925, p. 207).

l'auteur ne mentionne la façon dont les branches sont positionnées que parce que c'est justement à cause de la position des branches que ce qu'il y a derrière est en partie caché. L'auteur veut créer une atmosphère et ce n'est pas l'espèce végétale qui l'intéresse ici.
Il en va de même avec cette autre phrase :

Vous souvenez-vous de notre première rencontre, sous les branches tombantes des vieux pins sacrés, là-bas dans l'avenue sombre ? (ʀᴇ́ᴍʏ ᴅᴇ ɢᴏᴜʀᴍᴏɴᴛ, Sixtine, 1890)

où l'auteur se concentre sur le mouvement des branches qui contribue à l'atmosphère et ne parle pas d'une qualité quelconque de l'arbre d'un point de vue d'un botaniste.
Prenons un exemple qui ne soit plus du monde végétal. En couverture, une « faitière retombante » est une tuile avec un angle et au moins une face en pente (pour couvrir le sommet d'un mur par exemple).

Ah, tant de fois en traduction technique, ce terme m'est tombé dessus. Mais je finissais par retomber sur mes pieds. +1

Bien que voisins, les deux mots ne sont pas synonymes, et surtout pas interchangeables. Pour quelque chose qui pend (comme des branches, ou les oreilles d'un chien), on dira retombant si ça commence à monter avant de redescendre et tombant si ça n'a pas commencé par monter.
En ascii art, on aurait:
|  __          |
| /  \         |\
|/    \        | \
|      |       |  \
|              |   |
|              |
Retombant      Tombant

